# MySQL Query Statement converted to Codeigniter Active record style query statement with SUM()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Im trying to figure out the best way to convert this mysql query

```
SELECT
        SUM(invite.friendID = $mID AND invite.decidedwhen = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND evnt.ends >= '$event_ts' and invite.isactive = 0 and evnt.isactive = 0) AS invites_undecided,
        SUM(invite.friendID = $mID AND invite.decidedwhen != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND invite.yes = 1 AND evnt.ends >= '$event_ts' and invite.isactive = 0) and evnt.isactive = 0 AS invites_yes,
        SUM(invite.friendID = $mID AND invite.decidedwhen != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND invite.no = 1 AND evnt.ends >= '$event_ts' and invite.isactive = 0 and evnt.isactive = 0) AS invites_no,
        SUM(invite.friendID = $mID AND invite.decidedwhen != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND invite.maybe = 1 AND evnt.ends >= '$event_ts' and invite.isactive = 0 and evnt.isactive = 0) AS invites_maybe
FROM user_event_invite AS invite
JOIN user_event AS evnt ON evnt.eID = invite.eID
```

to something that uses Codeigniters active record formatting. EG

```
$this->db->select()
  ->from('user_event')
  ->... something?
```

The standard mysql statement works just fine. But in the name of sticking uniform to everything I'd like to use the active record. Any way of doing this? I can't find anything for `SUM()`

Comment: I searched up and down the guide for something like that, couldn't find it. However Im still at an bit of a hurdle, as it doesn't appear (based on the guide now that Ive found it) that I can use `select_sum` multiple times, and if I can? how would I factor in the various conditions per `SUM()` like I have above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(More of a comment than an answer as I've not tested it; but it may still help)

There is a `$this->db->select_sum();` function for the active record, and (this is the bit I'm not sure about) you probably can method chain. So here's something to try.

Stage 1 is to strip out the common stuff into a WHERE. If the WHERE is indexed, it'll speed things up. This will give you (with the parenthasis fixed too - your SQL has an error)

```
SELECT
    SUM(invite.decidedwhen = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS invites_undecided,
    SUM(invite.decidedwhen != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND invite.yes = 1 ) AS invites_yes,
    SUM(invite.decidedwhen != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND invite.no = 1) AS invites_no,
    SUM(invite.decidedwhen != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND invite.maybe = 1) AS invites_maybe
FROM user_event_invite AS invite
   JOIN user_event AS evnt ON evnt.eID = invite.eID
WHERE invite.friendID = $mID  AND evnt.ends >= '$event_ts' and invite.isactive = 0 AND evnt.isactive = 0
```

Also, if you can simplify by sayign accepting, making yes, no, maybe are all exclusive then you can strip off the "decidedwhen" as well to simplify further. (Ideally you'd just to a "COUNT" and subtract the rest, but not clear on how to do that in one query on the active record).

```
SELECT
    SUM(invite.decidedwhen = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS invitees_undecided,
    SUM(invite.yes = 1 ) AS invites_yes,
    SUM(invite.no = 1) AS invites_no,
    SUM(invite.maybe = 1) AS invites_maybe
FROM user_event_invite AS invite
   JOIN user_event AS evnt ON evnt.eID = invite.eID
WHERE invite.friendID = $mID  AND evnt.ends >= '$event_ts' AND invite.isactive = 0 AND evnt.isactive = 0
```

Now use that to method chain on the active record:

```
$this->db->select_sum('invite.decidedwhen = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'invite_undecided')
  ->select_sum('yes', 'invite_yes')
  ->select_sum('no', 'invite_no')
  ->etc
  ->from('user_event_invite')
  ->join('user_event', 'user_event.eID=user_event_invite.eID)
  ->where('friendID', '$mID')
  ->where('user_event.ends >=', $event_ts)
  -> etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      Like that you can write query :
    ==================================
     $query="SELECT SUM(case when invite.friendID = " . $mID ." AND 
     invite.decidedwhen = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND evnt.ends >= '" . $event_ts . "'
     and invite.isactive = 0 and evnt.isactive = 0) AS invites_undecided,...       
     FROM user_event_invite AS invite
      left outer JOIN user_event AS evnt ON evnt.eID = invite.eID"
```